# An OLE DB error has occurred. Error code: 0x80040E14, Invalid column name

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I have an ETL package built in SSIS that I'm trying to run but I'm getting this error, mainly the third one:

[image: Errors]

The part in the package that is giving the error is built like this:
[image: Architecture of the problematic part]

The specific component that is causing the error is the call to the SP and this are the parameters:
[image: Parameters passed to the SP]

The parameters are translated to:
[image: Parameters translation]

The parameters come from the query done at the start of the data flow:
[image: Query]

The error mentions invalid column 'P2' the only column that takes this value is SG_PLANO_CTB.

This is the SP that's being used:

```
USE [SISF_DW_REPORTING]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[SP_INSERT_EAF_MEMBER]    Script Date: 8/10/2018 11:22:07 AM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
-- Batch submitted through debugger: SQLQuery64.sql|7|0|C:\Users\SQL_AD~1.CMC\AppData\Local\Temp\3\~vs4CBB.sql
-- Batch submitted through debugger: SQLQuery29.sql|7|0|C:\Users\SQL_AD~1.CMC\AppData\Local\Temp\3\~vs8A81.sql
-- =============================================
-- Author:      
-- Create date: 
-- Description: This stored procedure creates the Early Arriving Fact for a given reference table
-- =============================================
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_INSERT_EAF_MEMBER]
     @TABLE                 NVARCHAR(50)
    ,@CD_REF                NVARCHAR(50)
    ,@LOG_ID                INT
    ,@ID_SK_COMPOSITE       NVARCHAR(50) = NULL
    ,@COL_SK_COMPOSITE      NVARCHAR(50) = NULL
    ,@DT_LOAD_DATE          INT = NULL
    ,@TABLE_FCT             NVARCHAR(50) = NULL
    ,@DEBUG                 BIT = 0

AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON

    IF 1=2
        BEGIN
            SELECT  CAST(NULL AS INT) AS ID_REF
                   ,CAST(NULL AS NVARCHAR(50)) AS DS_TBL_NAME
                   ,CAST(NULL AS NVARCHAR(50)) AS CD_SRCE_SYTM
                   ,CAST(NULL AS INT) AS LOG_ID
                   ,CAST(NULL AS INT) AS DT_LOAD_DATE
                   ,CAST(NULL AS NVARCHAR(50)) AS DS_TBL_FCT_NAME
        END
    --****************************************************
    SET @TABLE      = LTRIM(RTRIM(@TABLE))
    SET @CD_REF     = LTRIM(RTRIM(@CD_REF)) 
    SET @TABLE_FCT  = LTRIM(RTRIM(@TABLE_FCT))
    --****************************************************

    DECLARE @ID_INT_EAF INT
    DECLARE @ID_EAF NVARCHAR(100)
    DECLARE @DS_EAF NVARCHAR(100)
    DECLARE @DT_INT_EAF NVARCHAR(100)
    DECLARE @DT_DAT_EAF NVARCHAR(100)
    DECLARE @CD_INT_EAF NVARCHAR(100)
    DECLARE @CD_VAR_EAF NVARCHAR(100)
    DECLARE @FL_EAF NVARCHAR(4)
    DECLARE @NR_INT_EAF NVARCHAR(100)
    DECLARE @NR_VAR_EAF NVARCHAR(100)
    DECLARE @QT_EAF NVARCHAR(100)
    DECLARE @VL_EAF NVARCHAR(100)
    DECLARE @DMS_EAF NVARCHAR(100)
    DECLARE @GPS_EAF NVARCHAR(100)
    DECLARE @WGS_EAF NVARCHAR(100)
    DECLARE @DT_CRTN NVARCHAR(100)
    DECLARE @QUERY_FCT_LOAD_EAF VARCHAR(7000)
    DECLARE @QUERY_REF_EAF VARCHAR(7000)
    DECLARE @SG_EAF NVARCHAR(100)
    DECLARE @HR_EAF NVARCHAR(100)

    SET @ID_EAF = '-1'
    SET @DS_EAF = '''EAF Member ('+@CD_REF+')'''
    SET @DT_INT_EAF = '-1'
    SET @DT_DAT_EAF = '''1900-01-01'''
    SET @CD_VAR_EAF = ''''+@CD_REF+''''
    SET @CD_INT_EAF = '-1'
    SET @FL_EAF = '''-1'''
    SET @NR_INT_EAF = '0'
    SET @NR_VAR_EAF = '''EAF Member'''
    SET @QT_EAF = '''0'''
    SET @VL_EAF = '''0'''
    SET @DMS_EAF = '''EAF Member'''
    SET @GPS_EAF = '''EAF Member'''
    SET @WGS_EAF = '-1'
    SET @DT_CRTN = CONVERT(NVARCHAR(8),GETDATE(),112)
    SET @SG_EAF = '''EAF'''
    SET @HR_EAF = '''00:00:00'''

    -- Declare auxiliary variables
    DECLARE @TABLE_NAME NVARCHAR(50), @COLUMN_NAME NVARCHAR(100), @EAF_VALUE NVARCHAR(100)
    DECLARE @INSERT NVARCHAR(3000), @VALUES NVARCHAR(3000), @WHERE NVARCHAR(1000), @IDENTITY_ON NVARCHAR(1000), @IDENTITY_OFF NVARCHAR(1000)
    DECLARE @STATEMENT VARCHAR(7000)

    SET @IDENTITY_ON = 'SET IDENTITY_INSERT ' + @TABLE + ' ON;'
    SET @IDENTITY_OFF = 'SET IDENTITY_INSERT ' + @TABLE + ' OFF;'
    SET @INSERT = 'INSERT INTO ' + @TABLE + ' ('
    SET @VALUES = ' SELECT '


        BEGIN
            IF @COL_SK_COMPOSITE IS NULL
                SET @WHERE  = ' WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM ' + @TABLE + ' WHERE CD_' + SUBSTRING(@TABLE,9,LEN(@TABLE)) + ' = '''+@CD_REF+''');'
            ELSE
                SET @WHERE  = ' WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM ' + @TABLE + ' WHERE CD_' + SUBSTRING(@TABLE,9,LEN(@TABLE)) + ' = '''+@CD_REF+''' AND ' + @COL_SK_COMPOSITE + ' = ' + @ID_SK_COMPOSITE + ');'
        END

    DECLARE TABLE_COLUMNS CURSOR FOR  
    SELECT 
         C.TABLE_NAME
        ,C.COLUMN_NAME
        ,CASE
            WHEN @COL_SK_COMPOSITE IS NOT NULL AND LEFT(C.NEW_COLUMN_NAME,2) LIKE 'ID' AND C.NEW_COLUMN_NAME NOT LIKE 'ID_'+SUBSTRING(C.TABLE_NAME,5,LEN(C.TABLE_NAME)) AND C.NEW_COLUMN_NAME NOT LIKE 'ID_'+SUBSTRING(C.TABLE_NAME,9,LEN(C.TABLE_NAME)) 
            THEN @ID_SK_COMPOSITE
            WHEN @COL_SK_COMPOSITE IS NULL AND LEFT(C.NEW_COLUMN_NAME,2) LIKE 'ID' AND C.NEW_COLUMN_NAME NOT LIKE 'ID_'+SUBSTRING(C.TABLE_NAME,5,LEN(C.TABLE_NAME)) AND C.NEW_COLUMN_NAME NOT LIKE 'ID_'+SUBSTRING(C.TABLE_NAME,9,LEN(C.TABLE_NAME)) 
            THEN @ID_EAF
            WHEN LEFT(C.NEW_COLUMN_NAME,2) LIKE 'DS'
                THEN @DS_EAF
            WHEN C.NEW_COLUMN_NAME = 'DT_START' THEN '''1900-01-01'''
            WHEN C.NEW_COLUMN_NAME = 'DT_END' THEN '''9999-12-31'''
            WHEN LEFT(C.NEW_COLUMN_NAME,2) LIKE 'DT' THEN
                CASE
                    WHEN C.NEW_COLUMN_NAME LIKE 'DT_CRTN' THEN @DT_CRTN
                    WHEN C.DATA_TYPE LIKE 'int' THEN @DT_INT_EAF 
                    ELSE @DT_DAT_EAF END
            WHEN LEFT(C.NEW_COLUMN_NAME,2) LIKE 'CD' THEN
                CASE WHEN C.DATA_TYPE LIKE 'int' THEN @CD_INT_EAF ELSE @CD_VAR_EAF END
            WHEN LEFT(C.NEW_COLUMN_NAME,2) LIKE 'FL'
                THEN @FL_EAF
            WHEN LEFT(C.NEW_COLUMN_NAME,2) LIKE 'NR' THEN
                CASE 
                    WHEN C.DATA_TYPE LIKE 'int' THEN @NR_INT_EAF
                    WHEN C.DATA_TYPE LIKE 'numeric' THEN @NR_INT_EAF 
                    ELSE @NR_VAR_EAF END
            WHEN LEFT(C.NEW_COLUMN_NAME,2) LIKE 'QT'
                THEN @QT_EAF
            WHEN LEFT(C.NEW_COLUMN_NAME,2) LIKE 'VL'
                THEN @VL_EAF
            WHEN LEFT(C.NEW_COLUMN_NAME,3) LIKE 'DMS'
                THEN @DMS_EAF
            WHEN LEFT(C.NEW_COLUMN_NAME,3) LIKE 'GPS'
                THEN @GPS_EAF
            WHEN LEFT(C.NEW_COLUMN_NAME,3) LIKE 'WGS'
                THEN @WGS_EAF
            WHEN C.NEW_COLUMN_NAME = 'CTL_LOG_EAF'
                THEN '1'
            WHEN LEFT(C.NEW_COLUMN_NAME,7) LIKE 'CTL_LOG'
                THEN CAST(@LOG_ID AS NVARCHAR(50))
            WHEN @COL_SK_COMPOSITE IS NOT NULL AND LEFT(C.NEW_COLUMN_NAME,2) LIKE 'SG'
                THEN @ID_SK_COMPOSITE
            WHEN @COL_SK_COMPOSITE IS NULL AND LEFT(C.NEW_COLUMN_NAME,2) LIKE 'SG'
                THEN @SG_EAF
            WHEN LEFT(C.NEW_COLUMN_NAME,2) LIKE 'HR'
                THEN @HR_EAF
            ELSE '' 
            END EAF_VALUE
    FROM
        (
            SELECT
                 TABLE_NAME
                ,COLUMN_NAME
                ,CASE WHEN LEFT(COLUMN_NAME,2) LIKE 'X_' THEN SUBSTRING(COLUMN_NAME,3,LEN(COLUMN_NAME)) ELSE COLUMN_NAME END AS NEW_COLUMN_NAME
                ,DATA_TYPE
                ,ORDINAL_POSITION
            FROM
                INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
            WHERE COLUMN_NAME NOT LIKE 'ID_'+SUBSTRING(TABLE_NAME,9,LEN(TABLE_NAME))
        ) C
        INNER JOIN
        INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES T 
            ON C.TABLE_NAME = T.TABLE_NAME
    WHERE 
        T.TABLE_TYPE LIKE 'BASE TABLE'
        AND T.TABLE_NAME LIKE @TABLE
    ORDER BY 
        TABLE_NAME, ORDINAL_POSITION

    OPEN TABLE_COLUMNS   
    FETCH NEXT FROM TABLE_COLUMNS INTO @TABLE_NAME, @COLUMN_NAME, @EAF_VALUE; 

    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0  

    BEGIN   
        IF @COLUMN_NAME <> ''
            BEGIN
                SET @INSERT = @INSERT + @COLUMN_NAME + ', '
            END

        IF @EAF_VALUE <> ''
            BEGIN
                SET @VALUES = @VALUES + @EAF_VALUE + ', '
            END

        FETCH NEXT FROM TABLE_COLUMNS INTO @TABLE_NAME, @COLUMN_NAME, @EAF_VALUE; 
    END

    CLOSE TABLE_COLUMNS   
    DEALLOCATE TABLE_COLUMNS

    -- Final columns
    SET @INSERT = LEFT(@INSERT,LEN(@INSERT)-1) + ')'
    SET @VALUES = LEFT(@VALUES,LEN(@VALUES)-1)

    SET @QUERY_FCT_LOAD_EAF = 'INSERT INTO FCT_LOAD_EAF (ID_LOAD_DATE, ID_CRTN_DATE, DS_REF_TABLE_NAME, DS_FCT_TABLE_NAME, CD_SRCE_SYTM,CTL_LOG_INSERT) SELECT '+CAST(@DT_LOAD_DATE AS NVARCHAR(8))+', '+@DT_CRTN+', '''+@TABLE+''', '''+@TABLE_FCT+''', '''+@CD_REF+''', '+CAST(@LOG_ID AS NVARCHAR(50))+' '+@WHERE
    IF @DEBUG = 1 BEGIN SELECT @QUERY_FCT_LOAD_EAF END ELSE     BEGIN EXECUTE(@QUERY_FCT_LOAD_EAF) END
    PRINT @QUERY_FCT_LOAD_EAF

    SET @STATEMENT = @INSERT + @VALUES + @WHERE
    IF @DEBUG = 1 BEGIN SELECT @STATEMENT END ELSE  BEGIN EXECUTE(@STATEMENT) END 
    PRINT @STATEMENT

    IF LEFT(@TABLE,2) = 'X_'
        BEGIN
            SET @QUERY_REF_EAF = 'SELECT X_ID_'+SUBSTRING(@TABLE,7,LEN(@TABLE))+' AS ID_REF, ''' + @TABLE + ''' AS DS_TBL_NAME, CAST(X_CD_SRCE_SYTM AS NVARCHAR(50)) AS CD_SRCE_SYTM, '+CAST(@LOG_ID AS NVARCHAR(50))+' AS LOG_ID, '+CAST(@DT_LOAD_DATE AS NVARCHAR(8))+' AS DT_LOAD_DATE , ''' + @TABLE_FCT + ''' AS DS_TBL_FCT_NAME FROM '+@TABLE+' WHERE X_CD_SRCE_SYTM LIKE '''+@CD_REF+''''
            IF @DEBUG = 1 BEGIN SELECT @QUERY_REF_EAF END ELSE  BEGIN EXECUTE(@QUERY_REF_EAF) END
            PRINT @QUERY_REF_EAF
        END
    ELSE
        BEGIN
            SET @QUERY_REF_EAF = 'SELECT ID_'+SUBSTRING(@TABLE,5,LEN(@TABLE))+' AS ID_REF, ''' + @TABLE + ''' AS DS_TBL_NAME, CAST(CD_SRCE_SYTM AS NVARCHAR(50)) AS CD_SRCE_SYTM, '+CAST(@LOG_ID AS NVARCHAR(50))+' AS LOG_ID, '+CAST(@DT_LOAD_DATE AS NVARCHAR(8))+' AS DT_LOAD_DATE, ''' + @TABLE_FCT + ''' AS DS_TBL_FCT_NAME FROM '+@TABLE+' WHERE CD_SRCE_SYTM LIKE '''+@CD_REF+''''
            IF @DEBUG = 1 BEGIN SELECT @QUERY_REF_EAF END ELSE  BEGIN EXECUTE(@QUERY_REF_EAF) END
            PRINT @QUERY_REF_EAF
        END

    SET NOCOUNT OFF
END
```

I tried debugging the SP but I can't figure out where he builds the query that uses 'P2' as a column and not as value of the column SG_PLANO_CTB

Edit: I decided to log the parameters that were being used. Found out that the one causing the call causing the error is

```
exec SISF_DW_REPORTING..SP_INSERT_EAF_MEMBER 'REF_FIN_RUBRICA','11.1.1', 210999, 'P2', 'SG_PLANO_CTB'
```

And the query that's causing the error is

```
INSERT INTO REF_FIN_RUBRICA (CD_RUBRICA, DS_RUBRICA, CD_KEY, CD_PARENT, SG_PLANO_CTB, DT_START, DT_END, CTL_LOG_UPDATE, CTL_LOG_EAF) SELECT '11.1.1', 'EAF Member (11.1.1)', '11.1.1', '11.1.1', P2, '1900-01-01', '9999-12-31', 210999, 1 WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM REF_FIN_RUBRICA WHERE CD_RUBRICA = '11.1.1' AND SG_PLANO_CTB = P2);
```

I would guess the string delimitators aren't being added in the cursor somewhere. Can't see where though.

Comment: It looks like you may have a problem with the dynamic sql being generated. That's the only way I can think of a value ('P2') being referenced as column name. Is there any way you can capture the final value of `@QUERY_REF_EAF` from your proc? You'll need to find the syntax error in the generated query to be able to track down your logic error in the SP.

Comment: @digital.aaron I did some debug and I found the query, can't see where it's being misconstructed though. Added an edit

Comment: Search for "EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM" in your stored proc. That should narrow down the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to step through your generated proc logically, and I think I see where the issue lies. The call that's causing the error, `exec SISF_DW_REPORTING..SP_INSERT_EAF_MEMBER 'REF_FIN_RUBRICA','11.1.1', 210999, 'P2', 'SG_PLANO_CTB'` should probably be changed to:

```
exec SISF_DW_REPORTING..SP_INSERT_EAF_MEMBER 'REF_FIN_RUBRICA','11.1.1', 210999, '''P2''', 'SG_PLANO_CTB'
```

It looks like the dynamic sql generation takes the value of one of your input variables and uses that in the query string it builds. If your query needs a string value, you have to additionally double delimit it.